# Why the count of GridView items equals to zero?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and in my app I have a gridView that is filled with List of items .

Let's suppose that we have a list of users :

```
public class User
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
}

List<User> ListOfusers = new List<User>();
User user1 = new User();
user.UserId = 1;
user.UserName= "John";

User user1 = new User();
user.UserId = 2;
user.UserName= "Mike";

ListOfusers.Add(user1);
ListOfusers.Add(user2);   // Fill the list ( suppose that will be saved to the database )

GridView1.ItemsSource = ListOfusers;

// If I loaded again this window that contains the grid loaded from the database I got

Console.WriteLine(GridView1.ItemsSource); //  prints the objects 
Console.WriteLine(GridView1.Items.Count); //  prints 0
```

Why they are different in the output?

Comment: `Items` and `ItemsSource` refer to two different and mutually exclusive collections. See [What's the difference between a WPF DataGrid's Items and ItemsSource properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616369/whats-the-difference-between-a-wpf-datagrids-items-and-itemssource-properties).

Comment: But I have used them in the past and `Items.Count` gives the count of a grid, the same as that the count of objects that exist in `ItemsSource`